# TransitionEnd listener firing on child elements

Tags: javascript, css

I added a `transitionend` event listener to a `div`. This `div` has children who have transition on some elements. I want the transitionend event to only fire for the element I added it for, is this a bug? or expected behavior? How to make it fire only if its the one i added the listener to?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Events are bubbling by default, 
meaning that they will be "transmitted" to the parent element until they hit  the body or a handler that will stop them.

You can either :

- Filter by the [event's target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) being sure it's the element you're targetting.
- Listening to the event on children and [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) on them. That way, they won't bubble through the parent anymore.

If you'd show us some code, it would be easier to help you, depending on your current implementation.

Comment: Thanks for those options it was nice! I went with event.stopProp

Answer (score 6):

This process is called as `Event Bubbling`.The thing you can do is either detect the bubbling using the event handler or prevent the bubbling by stopping the propogation. You can do this by

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

In IE beofore 9.

You can do it as

```
window.event.cancelBubble = true;
```

Please have a detailed look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022336/why-the-transitionend-event-can-be-run-when-elements-childrens-transition-is-e)

Comment: Please don't mind but I accepted the other guys answer as he posted first. But your IE9 info and explanation is very much appreciated.

Comment: it okay man ..it doesnt matter about accepting the answer ..the matter is wheather if its helped you or not and am glad it helped you ..:) Cheers..Hapy coding