# Toggle function fires twice on transitionend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transitionend

I have a toggle whose `checked` status I am calling with jQuery. Every time I click the toggle from unchecked to checked, the console logs `"do this!"` twice. Why does this function fire twice and what is the workaround to get it to fire once?

```js
$("#my-toggle").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
  if (document.getElementById('my-checkbox').checked) {
    console.log("do this!")
  }
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before,
.slider .number {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider .number {
  background: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  left: 9px;
  top: 9px;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before,
input:checked+.slider .number {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" id="my-toggle"></span>
</label>
```

My final HTML looks like this, for which the event fires three times:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" id="my-toggle">
    <span class="number">00</span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, but I would like to know if there is a universal solution of finding if the status of such a toggle (that uses transition)  is checked or not without firing the function twice

Comment: can you try this may it can help you.   $("#my-toggle").on("click", function(){

if (!$('#my-checkbox').is(':checked')){
  alert("do this!")
}

 });

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using `transitionend webkitTransitionEnd etc.` instead of `click` when you're looking for a click event?

Comment: shouldn't the transition end before the checkbox input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `transitionend` events firing: one from your `#my-toggle` `<span>`, one from your `::before` pseudo element. You need to differentiate those two events. You’d need the event argument `e` for that.

The only difference is then found in `e.originalEvent.propertyName` (for the corresponding CSS property) and `e.originalEvent.pseudoElement`.

So let’s check for that last property in the `if` condition.

Also put another `&& e.target == this` in there, since the [`transitionend` event is also firing for children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26309838/4642212) because the event bubbles up. Since you’re only listening to the event on the parent `<span>`, you can’t simply call `e.stopPropagation` which would only be useful to prevent the *parent(s)* from firing the event.

```js
$("#my-toggle").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(e) {
  if (document.getElementById("my-checkbox").checked && !e.originalEvent.pseudoElement && e.target == this) {
    console.log("do this!");
  }
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before,
.slider .number {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider .number {
  background: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  left: 9px;
    top: 9px;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before,
input:checked + .slider .number {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id = "my-checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" id = "my-toggle">
     <span class="number">00</span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks - I apologize but I forgot to include an important part of the question.  I am also wrapping my slider in another span (to define the number inside the slider) - see edited question above.  However, the above code doesn't work and the function still fires twice after applying your solution. Why could that be?

Comment: @the_darkside It doesn’t work because your code turns out to be different.

Comment: what would need to be included apart from `&& !e.originalEvent.pseudoElement` in this case?  The `before:slider` pseudo element does not change in the edited question

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the elements that are concerned by the transition.
If you put a `console.log(event)` (with putting it as a argument of your event handler), you will see that the concerned properties are `background-color` and `trandform`.
These 2 properties are concerned by the transition, so your event hendler is called once per property.

Here is the snippet with "filtering" on `transform` property:

```js
$("#my-toggle").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(event){
  if (event.originalEvent.propertyName === "transform" && document.getElementById('my-checkbox').checked){
    console.log("do this!");
  }
 });
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" id="my-toggle"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: I don't see any visual difference between the OP's snippet and this one. It's related to a transition not a position or a color.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why if I include two `<spans>` , the proposed solution doesn't apply? See edited question above

Answer (score 0):

Use .slider instead of .switch when looking for the click function, this worked for me and I don't know why.

```
$('.slider').on('click',function(){


alert("Test");
});
```